# How to correctly use SimpleInjector - RegisterAllOpenGeneric

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I'm unable to figure out the correct way to use `RegisterAllOpenGeneric`

I have these simple definitions:

```
public interface ISubscribeTo<T> { }
public class AnEventOf<T> { }

public interface IMarker { }
public class PocoB : IMarker { }
```

and a *normal* `Subscriber`:

```
public class SubscribeToPocoB : ISubscribeTo<AnEventOf<PocoB>>
{
}
```

which is registered with this code:

```
private void RegisterSubscribers(Container container)
{
    var implementations = new List<Type>();

    container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(ISubscribeTo<>),
        AccessibilityOption.PublicTypesOnly,
        (serviceType, implTypes) =>
        {
            container.RegisterAll(serviceType, implTypes);

            implementations.AddRange(implTypes);
        },
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    );

    implementations
        .Distinct()
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(type => container.Register(type));

    container.Verify();
}
```

and is returned when calling:

```
var registrations = container
            .GetAllInstances<ISubscribeTo<AnEventOf<PocoB>>>();
```

All good so far.

`PocoB` also implements the interface `IMarker` and I am trying to create a `Subscriber` to `AnEventOf<IMarker>>` that will also be returned when calling `GetAllInstances<ISubscribeTo<AnEventOf<PocoB>>>();`.

I have tried 3 different definitions:

```
public class SubscribeToIMarker1<TMarker> : ISubscribeTo<AnEventOf<TMarker>>
    where TMarker : IMarker
{
}

public class SubscribeToIMarker2<TAnEventOf> : ISubscribeTo<TAnEventOf>
    where TAnEventOf : AnEventOf<IMarker>
{
}

public class SubscribeToIMarker3<TMarker> : ISubscribeTo<TMarker>
    where TMarker : IMarker
{
}
```

Here are the different tests methods I have written - none of the tests work, they all only return `SubscribeToPocoB`:

```
[Test]
public void GetAllInstances_PocoB1_ReturnTwoRegistrations()
{
    Container container = new Container();

    container.RegisterAllOpenGeneric(
        typeof(ISubscribeTo<>),
        typeof(SubscribeToIMarker1<>));

    RegisterSubscribers(container);

    var registrations = container
        .GetAllInstances<ISubscribeTo<AnEventOf<PocoB>>>();

    Assert
        .That(registrations.Count(),
            Is.EqualTo(2));
}

[Test]
public void GetAllInstances_PocoB2_ReturnTwoRegistrations()
{
    Container container = new Container();

    container.RegisterAllOpenGeneric(
        typeof(ISubscribeTo<>),
        typeof(SubscribeToIMarker2<>));

    RegisterSubscribers(container);

    var registrations = container
        .GetAllInstances<ISubscribeTo<AnEventOf<PocoB>>>();

    Assert
        .That(registrations.Count(),
            Is.EqualTo(2));
}

[Test]
public void GetAllInstances_PocoB3_ReturnTwoRegistrations()
{
    Container container = new Container();

    container.RegisterAllOpenGeneric(
        typeof(ISubscribeTo<>),
        typeof(SubscribeToIMarker3<>));

    RegisterSubscribers(container);

    var registrations = container
        .GetAllInstances<ISubscribeTo<AnEventOf<PocoB>>>();

    Assert
        .That(registrations.Count(),
            Is.EqualTo(2));
}
```

Do I need to do more than this to correctly register all open generics (e.g. `SubscribeToIMarker1`)?

```
container.RegisterAllOpenGeneric(
    typeof(ISubscribeTo<>),
    typeof(SubscribeToIMarker1<>));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RegisterAllOpenGeneric` is the collection equivalent of the `RegisterOpenGeneric` method. This means that you can register a set of open generic types as a collection. Just as with the `RegisterOpenGeneric` method however, the collection registered with `RegisterAllOpenGeneric` will only be resolved when there is no explicit registration.

In your case you make an explicit registration of a collection by calling `container.RegisterAll(Type, Type[])`. Since you registered this type explicitly, the registered collection of open generic types won't be built.

This is fine, but since your explicit collection registrations do not contain any open generic types, the resolved collection will only contain those registered non-generic types. Registering a set of open generic types using `RegisterAllOpenGeneric` does not automatically include them in any `RegisterAll` registrations.

So the solution is to register the open generic types as well. You can't however add the open generic types to the `RegisterAll` method, since this method only accepts closed generic types and non-generic types. The trick is to use the `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` overload that accepts both the callback delegate and a collection of `Type`s. This overload accepts open generic types and will distribute the closed generic versions back to the callback delegate.

This is what your `RegisterSubscribers` method should look like:

```cs
private void RegisterSubscribers(Container container)
{
    Type[] openGenericSubscribers = new[]
    { 
        typeof(SubscribeToIMarker1<>),
        typeof(SubscribeToIMarker2<>),
        typeof(SubscribeToIMarker3<>)
    };

    var nonGenericSubscribers = OpenGenericBatchRegistrationExtensions
        .GetTypesToRegister(container,
            typeof(ISubscribeTo<>),
            AccessibilityOption.PublicTypesOnly,
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

    container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(ISubscribeTo<>),
        container.RegisterAll,
        nonGenericSubscribers.Concat(openGenericSubscribers));

    container.RegisterAllOpenGeneric(typeof(ISubscribeTo<>), 
        openGenericSubscribers);

    container.Verify();
}
```

What's happening here is that instead of calling the `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` that accepts a collection of `Assembly` objects, we call the `OpenGenericBatchRegistrationExtensions.GetTypesToRegister` method to get the list of non-generic subscribers. The `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` overload that accepts a collection of `Assembly` uses this method under the covers.

Next we supply the list of non-generic subscribers to the `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` overload that accepts the callback delegate and a collection of `Type` objects, but we concat the open generic subscribers to the collection of supplied types.

The `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` will group the supplied list of non-generic types based on the closed generic `ISubscribeTo<T>` interface they implement (and might place on type in multiple groups if it implements multiple `ISubscribeTo<T>` interfaces). When the groups are constructed the callback delegate is called with the `ISubscribeTo<T>` service type and the grouped implementation types.

But before calling the callback delegate, this specific `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` does a last thing. It will iterate the list of supplied open generic implementations (`SubscribeToIMarker1<T>`, 2 and 3 in this case) and will try to construct closed generic versions based on the closed generic `ISubscribeTo<T>` version. This is of course done based on the given type constraints. All closed generic implementations that were constructed will be concatted to the list of implementations.

This means that in the end the `container.RegisterAll` will be called and both non-generic and closed generic types are passed in.

The `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` can't magically make up new generic types out of nothing, so it will only call the callback delegate with an closed `ISubscribeTo<T>` service type for which he finds a non-generic implementation that implements a closed `ISubscribeTo<T>`. So this means that `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` won't allow us to resolve collections that consist solely of closed-generic types. For this we need the `RegisterAllOpenGeneric` and that's what the last statement in the `RegisterSubscribers` does. It registers a fallback collection with solely closed-generic types in case there is no explicit registration for a collection.

Since you call `RegisterAllOpenGeneric` within the `RegisterSubscribers` method, you will have to remove the `RegisterAllOpenGeneric` calls from within your unit tests. And when you do, you'll see your tests passing.

Comment: Ah, a simple solution! Out of interest - of the 3 open generic definitions in the question only the first one `SubscribeToIMarker1<TMarker> : ISubscribeTo<AnEventOf<TMarker>>' is returned (it's not a problem as it's the one that makes sense).

Comment: @qujck: If that's the only one that's returned, its because the others don't match because of their generic type constraints.